# Does the bootsrap "row" and "col-xs, col-lg..." classes contain margin, padding?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row, margin

I'm not able to get the exact information about what are margins, paddings and all alignment styling included in the "row" and "col-xs-*, col-lg-*..." classes

I found on bootstrap documentation `http://getbootstrap.com/css/`under Grid options documentation a few informations, but i does not specify what are exactly the margins and the paddings...

Can you please tell me what are the paddings, margins, and all alignement stylings related to those classes or orient me to a documentation on the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean alignment styling? Do you mean text alignment? Floating columns?

Comment: No it's the paddings and margins specifically

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses gutters (padding on each side of the column), they do not use margins.

from their documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

**Gutter width  30px (15px on each side of a column)**

Comment: Thanks ! Do they use 15px for all media queries ? ( xs, sm,md and lg)

Comment: And what about "row" class ? Does it have any padding/margin ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the bootstrap 3 CSS source, you can look there.  See below:

```
.col-xs-1 ... .col-xs-12 {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! What about col-lg-* for example ? Are the paddings standerized for all xs, sm, md and lg ?

Comment: And what about "row" class ? Does it have any padding/margin ?

Comment: Yes, the padding is the same for all cols and row has -15px margin on both left and right.

Comment: Cool ! Also, i am using bootstrap-rails and when i inspect the code i see for  padding-left: 12.5px for col-xs-8, and margin-left: -12.5px for row.
Is it normal to have this difference for the normal 15px for bootstrap-rails ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.